# Loading files from custom section specified in web.config even after change to those files

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I want to add a custom section in the `ConfigSections` of my web.config and then on application load, load that file into memory. My only problem is I have a few files and one of them will be generated on a daily basis and accessed in the project. I would like read the new values every time that file changes.

Is that even possible?

Comment: What code have you written to do this?  Please post it if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean.

If you mean that web.config is auto generated then your web site will be restarted whenever that happens.

If you mean a different file you should look into the FileSystemWatcher class which can be configured to raise an event whenever a file is changed.

Comment: I have a web.config and I will be making a entry in ConfigSection for this particular class. The class wil be responsible to load the xml file that I specify and create an object of that class in memory at application start up.

But the XML file may change and I would like to get that object again. I am not sure if there is a way to load such an object in memory once the XML has changed.

Comment: It seems to me that you should use FileSystemWatcher and some XmlSerialization, it should be fairly easy to google.